# How to execute the function only after state changed in the caller (some callback) without useEffect in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

In a class component it's pretty easy to provide the desired order. If the state changes we always know when it *really* changed:

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

From the documentation: "setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied."

I need to execute a function with 100% guarantee *after* some state variable change and I need it to be done **at the caller** (because sometimes I don't need to call the function, so I can't useEffect here). Something like that:

```
setVar(10);
callFuncHere(); // <======= No guarantee var == 10 at the moment
```

Comment: Can't be done without `useEffect` most likely

Comment: `(because sometimes I don't need to call the function, so I can't useEffect here)` Why can't you apply the same logic in `useEffect` and prevent calling the function in these specific cases?

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç I thought about this too but I can't figure out how I can apply the logic. I have an object changed, there is no way to pass some parameter or flag and there is no way to see if other state variable changed with 100% guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I see there are a lot of similar questions. But NONE of them has an appropriate solution. People suggest using useEffect but they don't think it's a different story.

I tried different solutions but nothing worked. Then I came to the direct brutal solution: I'm just using the global variable defined outside of the component. Then I can add the logic to useEffect and call or not call some specific function:

```
var flag = false;

useEffect(() => {
        if (flag){
            callFUnc();
            flag = false;
        }
    }, [someVar]);

...

flag = true;
setVar(newVal)
```

I hope this solution will help someone. What I wonder is WHY nobody in Facebook.React doesn't see the difference between a callback in setState and useEffect??